# Enable CKEditor on a field with a custom widget

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have a custom widget for a field that hides the field if certain conditions are not met. My custom widget field extends the `StringTextareaWidget` class as a base. When it renders, my widget never displays ckeditor.

If I change the display widget to "Text Area (multiple rows)" ckeditor displays as expected.

To test my code, I commended out everything except the class declaration that extends StringTextAreaWidget, and this also prevents the ckeditor from displaying when the widget is rendered. How do I get my custom field widget to display with ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was extending the wrong class from my field widget. The proper class to extend if you're looking to use CKEditor is `TextareaWidget`